# How to get the new cherry picked branch to be pushed up for review?

Tags: git

I did some bug fixes on branches from what we can call an original master project, those branches were pushed, then there was an unrelated issue where I ended up blowing away the project and doing a fresh install of the project to master.

So now those branches have been pushed they are out there and so what I did was after cloning a fresh project was to create a new branch:

`git checkout -b ENGA-1651`, it's the same name as the branch that was already pushed for review.

Then I did a `git cherry-pick abc12345` onto it, but if I do a `git status` it shows nothing to commit.

From this point, how do I verify that the `git cherry-pick` worked and how do I get the new branch with the cherry picked commit to be the branch we use moving forward without confusing it with the old branch?

This is what I saw when I executed the command:

```
git:(ENGA-1651) ✗ git cherry-pick 19da8a5d84a
[ENGA-1651 09ce462d] ENGA-1651:updated dropdown menu to include DC
 Date: Fri May 17 15:21:18 2019 -0500
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

The cherry pick confuses me because it has the date of the original `git push` instead of what I just cherry picked today.

I then tried to do a `git push` and got this error:

```
git:(ENGA-1651) ✗ git push --set-upstream origin ENGA-1651
To https://bitbucket.nfib.org/scm/enga/engage-application.mobile.git
 ! [rejected]          ENGA-1651 -> ENGA-1651 (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://CortesD@bitbucket.nfib.org/scm/enga/engage-application.mobile.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

I don't want to do a `git pull` if it's going to grab the changes from the remote branch I originally pushed, that's the whole purpose of just cherry picking what I wanted out of it. What do I do here?

Comment: could you do cherry pick or the commits are too much?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon, so would that entail creating a new branch and then doing a `git cherry-pick commit123` to it? I have heard of cherry pick but this would be my first time using it, if this is the way to go. It's only one commit.

Comment: What do you mean by "pushed"? Pushed to where?

Comment: @melpomene, I updated my post.

Comment: I still don't understand what the situation is or what you're asking. Can you show an example (files with changes, commit history, etc.)?

Comment: I can't tell what the situation is but a push -f to replace the prior pushed branch with the one that you just created might be the solution if permitted.

Comment: @melpomene, I added more detail.

Comment: @DanD., `git push -f origin <branch_name>`?

Comment: That would be the full command and it can be undone if needed via the remotes reflog.

Comment: @DanD., could you take a look at my post again, I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me you need to delete the remote branch first by doing
  git push --delete origin ENGA-1651

And then push your local branch
  git push origin ENGA-1651

Cherry-pick commit will have the original time since the commit you picked is the "same"

Comment: Dont I need to cherry pick it before I delete it?

Comment: It depends on where the commits you want to cherry-pick are and whether you keep the commit ids. It shouldn't matter if you delete the remote branch first since cherry-pick operation is local.